# JupyterLab plotly extension error: Cannot find module jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\ejs\postinstall.js

Tags: node.js, npm, plotly, ejs, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install JupyterLab renderer support for Plotly using:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.10.0
```

and I get

> RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

The log file contains the following:

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v14.11.0

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @lumino/coreutils@1.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\ejs: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./postinstall.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\ejs
Output:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\ejs\postinstall.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] npm dependencies failed to install
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 138, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 134, in start
    build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 459, in build
    return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 652, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

When I open JupyterLab I am asked to do a

```
jupyter lab build
```

After my attempt, I get the same error in the logfile.

I am using Windows10, node.js 14.11.0 (installed using conda), JupyterLab 2.1.5

Note that I have tried:

- uninstalling conda's node.js and installing node.js directly from node-v12.18.3-x64.msi
- uninstalling and installing Anaconda

both with no luck.

Comment: What happens if you try and install ejs by itself `$ npm install ejs`?

Comment: I get the same, it seems you have to install it into an existing project

Comment: @DavidBradshaw Could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: I mean you can only run npm install ejs inside an existing node project that has a package.json file in it

Comment: Are you behind any sort of proxy ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your previous comment, you confirmed that you are not behind any proxy, which is one of the most common reason for these errors. Even I tried installing the jupyter lab and plotly extension, as I also wanted to give it a try, it worked for me without any error.

Issue can be very specific with your environment. And mostly because of corrupt npm package. You can try any of below step, it may do the trick

1. Move to directory `C:\Users\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging`, and delete `node_module` folder. After deleting folder try running command `yarn install` from same folder. If no error then you should be good.
2. If above doesn't work, you can reset yarn cache using command `yarn cache clean`. And retry step 1.
3. Still if it doesn't work, try deleting `yarn.lock` file, then step 2 and 1.

Node: Please backup the files you are going to delete. Also there is no way to tell which step will work for you, its just hit and trial.

Comment: I tried 1 and 2 and I got a popup with a title: Windows Script Host: Script C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js. Line:1, Char:1, Error: Invalid character, Code 800A03F6, Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error. I also tried step 3 but I got the same error. Note that the first line of yarn.js contains: #!/usr/bin/env node

Comment: I decided to delete yarn.js and then I reinstalled it via https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable. I then retried steps 2 and 1. I got no errors and proceeded with jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.10.0. It worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with firewall.

Try setting a proxy in `npm`'s config, or even turn `strict-ssl` off:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

and

```
npm config set proxy http://host:port
```

for `http`

or

```
npm config set https-proxy https://host:port
```

for `https`

Comment: I am not behind a proxy. Changed the strict-ssl off but nothing changed :(

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.. I'll try to thing about other options.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I think see why this is happening, version 2 of `ejs` had a post install script, but it was removed from version 3. It looks like another package `cjs` is trying to directly call `ejs/postInstall.js` for some reason.

It looks like you have some dependancies out of sync. My suggestion would to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and try the install command again.

If that doesn't work look for any other lock files, such as `yarn.lock` and delete them and `node_modules` again.

Good luck

Comment: if none of that works try deleting `ejs` from `node_modules` and then install `ejs@2.7`

Comment: I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json from C:\users\<user> and run npm install ejs. Then tried to install the jupyterlab extention but I got the same error again. I could not find any yarn.lock. Finally, I deleted ejs and run npm install ejs@2.7. I got the same error once again.

Comment: You need to do this in C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\